# Google sheets: formatting Query request

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a query resulting

[image: table]

1th column - ids 1000 1001 1002
2th column - items item1 item2 item3

How can i pack this table in one cell as follows: item1 1000, item2 1001, item3 1002
Join can't concatenate tables, maybe i should use arrayformula, but i dont know how.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Get each separate row with [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275).
- Concatenate all resulting rows with [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992).

Resulting formula could be this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B & " " & A2:A),B2:B<>""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** 
Concat the Column 2 (item) and Column 1 (id) with `TEXTJOIN` formula and space `" "` character as delimiter

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ", false,B1,A1)
```

**Step 2 :**
Concat the result column obtained from the `Step 1` with `TEXTJOIN` formula and comma `","` character as delimiter ignoring the empty

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,C:C)
```

[image]